# android adb won't start

Tags: android

I can't get the adb to run. From the dos line when I type adb I get "error: write failure during connection. I'm running Motodev's eclipse (probably Ganymede or Galileo) on windows XP. I've reinstalled eclipse and android three times from an administrator's account, and I've removed all virus software from the computer.

The complete error dump is:

_adb_connect: host:version
   socket_loopback_client: port 5037 type tcp => fd 100
   writex: 100 0022BB57 4:  30303063  000c
   _socket_set_errno: unhandled value 10022
   writex 100 -1 Invalid argument
   adb_close: 100(lo-client:5037)
   error: write failure during connection

any ideas as to what's stopping adp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "adb kill-server"

Stop all Emulators, Eclipse and other processes that are using adb. Do a "ps -all" and check that no other adb processes are running.

Then try again. Let us know if you still face the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't have any other services that might interfere with it (like Droid Explorer) running. it took me almost a week to figure out that DroidExplorer was constantly over-riding adb..

Answer (score 0):

If still having problems you can uncheck BOTH MTP & PTP on the device then run adb devices from command line inside the Android SDK\platformtools directory. Allow the RSA fingerprint on the device if prompted. Should be good to go if adb devices shows device.