# ADB missing in Ubuntu for HTC Desire S?

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

So I switched from Win to Ubuntu 11.10 for my Android development. In the same way as ADB drivers for Win7 was a problem, something weird is happening in Ubuntu as well. I try to run a (runnable) application, but my connected Desire S is somehow not recognized. See the what happens here:

[image: Error message when trying to connect]

I have tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160037/android-adb-wont-start) but it doesn't help. Do I have to install something to make this work? Really annoying that this issue arises in Ubuntu as well, I thought it was not supposed to?

Comment: Ok, so the issue is likely the udev rules. I tried doing what is described in the links, but when I executed "adb devices" from the "platform-tools" folder the command "adb" is not recognized. What am I missing then?

Comment: I removed and reinstalled the ia32-libs package (don't know if it made any difference) and rebooted the computer after doing what you guys described. Works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have not given permissions in Ubuntu to access the Phone
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a driver problem.

You might want to check the link below in order to add the line for HTC devices in the android.rules file.

[Setting Up ADB/USB Drivers for Android Devices in Linux (Ubuntu)](http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add an udev rules in linux, for your mobile. For instance,

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
```

where you can retrive the idVender with `lsusb`

Comment: Thanks. For Ubuntu 12.04 I had to use ATTRS instead of SYSFS. Example for HTC devices: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"`

Answer (score 1):

Run lsusb after connecting your device then look at the vendorid and product id. Add it to your udev file.

Should be similar to https://github.com/mrothe/desire-udev/blob/master/99-desire.rules

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I hope my answer helps someone if they have the same problem and find this answer via search engines like me.

For my HTC Wildfire S A510E, I needed to add

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cb0", MODE="0666", GROUP="my-user-group"
```

into /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules in my Ubuntu 14.04.1.

You can find the full list here http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/android (in French)